# PHP file downloading rather than executing in my xampp in ubuntu

Tags: php, xampp

i am trying to run my file on local host, but when ever i do submit button it pops up to download a PHP file which HTML has link to it. its working fine in mac but not in UBUNTU. please tell me the best solution to it.

```
<HTML>
<head>
<title>MOVIE DATABASE SYSTEM</title>
<link  href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
<center>Movie Database System</center>
</div>
<form method="POST" action="add_movie.php" >
Movie Number:<br>
<input TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Movie_id" required><br><br>
Title:<br>
<input TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Title" required><br><br>
Year:<br>
<input TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Year" required><br><br>
Plot:<br>
<input TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Plot" required><br><br>
Movie Length:<br>
<input TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Length" required><br><br>
<a href="#"><button>SUBMIT</button>
<button>CANCEL</button></a>
</form>
<a href="admin.html"><button>ADMIN HOME</button></a>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Please provide the code of your <form> line.

Comment: Are you sure PHP is properly configured in Apache

Comment: Is your server is configured to run PHP files ?
Can you show us the php.ini and httpd.conf files ?

Comment: i am not sure. i tried to find .so file but i don't know where it is in my php folder. @RiggsFolly

Comment: You are launching this from the browsers address bar arn't you?

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the html file directly in your in your web browser as a file. You instead need to access it through your web server by going to http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1 (depending on how your configuration is set). I am also assuming you have a web server running on that computer.

Your default web directory is likely in /var/www or /var/www/html.

If you have not installed a web server you can install apache like this:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```